# check for open appointment dates

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with this:

```
--------------
booked_dates 
--------------
2017-11-28
2017-11-27
2017-11-26
2017-11-25
2017-11-24
2017-11-23
2017-11-22
2017-11-21
2017-11-20
2017-11-19
2017-11-18
2017-11-17
2017-11-07
2017-11-06
2017-11-05
2017-11-04
2017-11-03
2017-11-02
2017-11-01
--------------
```

I have a search form and I have it set to return either YES or NO (availability)

If people searched between 2017-11-02 (to) and 2017-11-26 (from) and check for a 3-day slot, the search should return YES as there is a free 3 days between 2017-11-07 and 2017-11-17.

I've been trying to use TIMESTAMPDIFF but struggling trying to find the right query.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is probably the simplest solution here. Sach for the "next date" after each booking_date, then calculate the difference (in days). If that period equals or exceeds the comparison period, return yes. Optionally return he max available period too.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c90a/1)

**Query 1**:

```
select
    case when max(avail) >= 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end is_avail
  , max(avail) max_period
from (
      select 
        datediff(
                 (select booked_date from booked_dates n
                  where n.booked_date > b.booked_date
                  order by n.booked_date
                  limit 1)
               ,  booked_date
                ) avail
      from booked_dates b
      where b.booked_date between '2017-11-02' and '2017-11-26'  
    ) a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c90a/1/0)**:

```
| is_avail | max_period |
|----------|------------|
|      Yes |         10 |
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you know what day is free day

```
SELECT IF(count(a.dates)>=3,'Yes','No')availability 
FROM booked_dates a 
left join (
     SELECT w.dates 
     FROM booked_dates w where w.dates between  '2017-11-07' and '2017-11-17'
    ) free on free.dates = a.dates 
where a.dates between  '2017-11-02' and '2017-11-26'  
and free.dates is not null
```

Comment: actually, that data isn't important. just like to return true or false if there is a free 3-day slot (if that is the search)